# Change children's Apple ID

Tags: apple-id, children, family-sharing

I accidentally created an @icloud.com address for my kid's (under 13) Apple ID, and now I want to change the primary email to his correct address. However, there is no option for setting a new primary email when I sign into his account at [appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com). The correct address is listed under *Alternative Email Addresses*
 I thought maybe I'd have to change it through my account, but I couldn't find any help there either. How can I change his primary email address?

**EDIT:** The only buttons next to the alternative email address are *edit* and *delete*. There are no buttons next to the primary address. Both addresses are verified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://appleid.apple.com/ is the correct place.

It's been awhile since I did this, but as I recall you will need to delete it as the secondary email then you can edit the primary.

Also, it's easiest if you turn off FindMyiPhone on the device before starting this process.  After all changes have been made and you are logged back into iCloud on the device using the new appleid then be sure and turn FindMyiPhone back on. (FindMyiPhone is a security feature and one it's purposes is to make it difficult for someone without the appleId details to log out. Changing your appleId can confuse the secuirty features, solution is to turn it off during this process.)

Also realize that once you have made the change at appleid.apple.com, the are multiple places in settings on the phone to logout and log back in under the new: iCloud, iTunes and App Store, facetime, messages, Game Center, and likely email needs setup changes.

Edit (based on OP's comment below): [Apple states](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667) that "If your email address ends with @icloud.com, @me.com, or @mac.com, it's already an Apple ID." Therefor it's not going to be possible to make this appleid have a different primary email address.  If you want an appleid using your son non @icloud.com address you will have to create it.  In order for that to happen you may have to delete it as the secondary on this account.  There is logic in no edit button appearing for the primary. If you made this appleid differnt, how could the @icloud address still be an appleid?

Comment: Correct; your primary email can't be the same as the secondary email.

Comment: You've got some good advices there, but not the answer I am looking for. See my edited question for some details I should've mentioned in first place.

Comment: @anustart there should be as edit button (but not a delete button) for primary.  Can you try a different browser? Probably not the issue, but it's worth eliminating it.  Are there purchases or anything attached to this appleid? If not you could create new and abandon current.

Comment: see new edit. I don't think you are going to be able to change the appleid in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If an Apple ID is created as an iCloud.com account, you are unable to change the primary email address. You can add a rescue email address to the account, in order to make changing passwords or resetting security questions easier.